# instantiate a template class using pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to instantiate a template class using pointer, for example:

```
vector<*vector<int> >
```

But it won't work. Complier(g++) indicates "template argument 1 is invalid". Any idea about this situation? Is this my wrong to write or template class can't be instantiated by pointer in nature.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is my stupid mistake, it should be vector<vector<int>*>.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> vector_of_pointers_to_vector_of_ints;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is my fault.

Comment: @Xiangyu No worries :)

Comment: This is an example how inconsistent C++'s syntax is!